# using same address for send and recv in MPI_Allreduce

Tags: c++, mpi

Is it safe to use the same input and output buffer for `MPI_Allreduce` in general? It seems that openmpi still works with that on Linux/Ubuntu.

```
int max_quantities = ...;
MPI_Allreduce(&max_quantities, &max_quantities, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, comm);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never "alias" buffers. Some MPI implementations explicitly give you an error about it. Instead use `MPI_IN_PLACE`:

````
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &max_quantities, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, comm);

```
````

Comment: that's great to know there is MPI_IN_PLACE. Is it in the MPI standard?

Comment: Absolutely. Let me remark that if you do `MPI_Reduce` instead of `allreduce` the in-place parameter becomes tricky: on the root process it goes in first location, on all others in second.